# traceroute command details

Tags: networking, ttl, router

As I see in wikipedia, traceroute utility sends a sequence of packets using ICMP protocol in groups of three and with incrementing TTL value to identify the network routers. It also says that Internet Protocol doesn`t guarantee that all the packets take the same route.

So I have three questions:

1- Why are THREE packets sent for each router?

2- What would happen if these three packets with the same TTL value traverse in different routing ways?

3- When these routes can be changed during the time for different packet groups, how can the result be useful?!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The main benefit is to make sure
   you get a response even with packet
   loss. Other benefits include
   getting more data points for round
   trip time, and seeing if different
   packets take different routes.
2. It would print the gateway for
       each packet.
3. The point in running a traceroute is to
       see where the packets go, if your
       traceroute is showing a constantly
       varying route, then the rest of your
       packets are doing the same. Seems to me just as useful to know this as learning your route is essentially static.

   That said, just because the
       routes aren't prevented from changing, doesn't mean they
       do. Most of the time when you run
       traceroute you're going to get the
       same route. Changing routes happen mostly with transient conditions, e.g. when a given router gets too busy.

Answer (score 2):

- It often uses UDP or even TCP (tcptraceroute is often more useful, or the -t option on some implementations) for the outgoing packets- but in all cases relies on ICMP TTL exceeded messages.
- Traceroute is a clever hack on tcp/ip - not a built-in function to discover routes.  It was a clever afterthought.
- You can specify different numbers of packets to send- doesn't have to be three.
- As Kowh said - routes can change, but don't necessarily change that often.  There are many reasons traceorute may give misleading results - from ICMP having a lower priority, or being blocked entirely - the important part is to understand the mechanics of how it works and what it is and isn't telling you.